# 'mod' and -1 in haskell

Tags: haskell

how come that following piece gives 4?

```
(\x -> (x-1) `mod` 5) 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

-1 [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) 5 is, by definition, 4.

Comment: it differs by programming language, and by which mod function you use

Answer (score 6):

Because mod is defined as positive. div and mod operate on a floor basis, while / and rem do not.

```
Prelude> let x=(-2)
Prelude> let y=5
Prelude> (x`div`y)*y+(x`mod`y)
-2
Prelude> y*(truncate ((fromInteger x)/fromInteger y)) + (x`rem`y)
-2
Prelude> x`rem`y
-2
Prelude> x`mod`y
3
Prelude> (fromInteger x)/fromInteger y
-0.4
Prelude> x`div`y
-1
```

Addendum: As KennyTM rightly points out, I should have used quot, not /:

```
Prelude> (x`quot`y)*y+(x`rem`y)
-2
Prelude> (x`quot`y)
0
```

I simply did not remember it, and was too hasty to look it up. quot will do an integer division.

Comment: The correspondence of `div` should be `quot`, not `/`.